# SSL Requests on staging environments fail

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl

Our mobile app recently stopped authenticating properly with our server on our staging and staging2 environments. Fortunately production is fine.

We're using `force_ssl` in our API's Session and Registration controllers. It was working fine  before; not really sure what changed.

What seems to be happening is that our app submits a POST request to either create a new session or user. This request is over SSL, but we get a `301 Moved Permanently` with a location identical to the initial request. I believe this redirect is performed via GET and since no routes match a GET to that URL, we then get a `404 Not Found`.

I can't figure out why this changed recently and why it's not affecting production.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was something having to do with Engine Yard, and an upgrade of our environment solved the problem.